# How Can I Share Authorization between main application and virtual application in Open ID Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, asp.net-authorization

I have created one application in asp.net mvc 5.In which I am using open id azure for authorization purpose.

Now there is one module ,which is separate project, that I want to host as independent application as virtual directory inside main application.

I am getting problem with authorization.

when i am calling my virtual directory controller.even though  main application is authorized,it shows me authorization error.

What should I do?

Image:[Project Strtucture In IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ygLF.jpg)

Here I attached screen shot to explain my scenario.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this question properly. Config can be nested, so if the authentication for the child is different to the authentication of the parent you may have issues there

Comment: what information you want from my end?

Comment: Paths - or example paths, how each application is configured for authentication in the web.config, whether or not it works correctly with authentication switched off